# É possível adicionar um ouvinte de evento na url?

Tags: javascript, ajax, url

A ideia é que, quando houver uma mudança na url, execute uma função que fará algo com essa url, por exemplo, o usuário está na página `exemplo.com/#/algumacoisa/2` que é uma tabela com paginação, no caso, ele estaria na página 2, e quando a url mudar para `exemplo.com/#/algumacoisa/4`, atualize a tabela com os dados da página 4, semelhante ao que o angular faz.

É possível fazer isso sem ter que chamar a função quando o usuário clicar no botão de "próxima página" ou algo assim.

**Observação**: quando ele clicar no botão "próxima página" ou algo assim, a página não irá recarregar, apenas alterar a url, ou seja, não adianta simplesmente criar uma função autoinvocada em algum lugar do código

Comment: @dvd pensei em fazer assim, adicionando ouvintes de evento em todos links, mas ainda assim daria uma mão, e se eu carregar outros htmls via ajax teria que adicionar os eventos novamente

Comment: Se o que quer é monitorar mudanças após o hash (`#`), pode usar o [evento `hashchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/hashchange).

Comment: Poderia responder com um exemplo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exemplo de uso do evento [`hashchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/hashchange):

```js
var out = document.getElementById('output');
window.addEventListener('hashchange', function(e) {
    out.innerHTML = 'hash atual: ' + window.location.hash;
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 10px 0;
  min-height: 16px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#div1">Link 1</a><br>
<a href="#div2">Link 2</a><br>
<a href="#div3">Link 3</a><br>

<div id="div1">div1</div>
<div id="div2">div2</div>
<div id="div3">div3</div>

<div id="output"></div>
```